# Global Variables not working

Tags: vba, global-variables

I have a problem with global variable

I'm working with modules in vba

-- In module5 is define the global variable

```
Public tes As Integer
```

-- In module6 I define the "tes"

```
Function a()
    tes = 1
End Function
```

-- In module I try to call "tes" variable

```
Sub test()
    MsgBox tes
End Sub
```

I suppose the result should show 1, but it show 0

I wonder what's wrong

Thanks

Randy

Comment: Do you call `Function a()` before calling `Sub test()`?

Comment: Is `Module5` a *standard module* (.bas) or a *class module* (.cls)?

Comment: should it not be a public function?

Comment: @mo.h unless it's specified otherwise, any module member in a VBA module is implicitly `Public`, so it *is* a public function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `a` never runs, `tes` is never assigned. Make sure `a` runs before you read `tes` and the msgbox will show 1:

```
Sub test()
    a
    MsgBox tes
End Sub
```

That said, it's probably better to pass `tes` as a parameter instead of sprinkling global variables that can be modified from anywhere.

```
Sub DoSomething()
    Dim foo As Integer
    foo = 1
    Test foo
End Sub
```

```
Sub Test(ByVal value As Integer)
    MsgBox value
End Sub
```

Variables should usually be as tightly scoped and short-lived as possible; use globals only when you **need** them (that should be *rarely*), not *everytime a function/procedure needs to access some data*.